# Oozie Java Action System.out

Tags: java, hadoop, oozie

I have oozie java action. After successfully completition of the job, I can't find `System.out.println` output in the oozie log. I'm looking at  web console "Job Log" screen. I see log output there related to my oozie job but not `System.out.println` output. How can I configure oozie so that I can see outputs of `System.out.println?

Answer (score 1):

You should override log4j.properties which is inside the hadoop jar file:

```
-D log4j.configuration=PATH_TO_FILE
```

(with a spacebar)

For instance:

```
oozie job -oozie "$oozieServerUrl" -config $ooziePath/coordinator.properties -D log4j.configuration=PATH_TO_FILE -run -verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find these output inside containers of yarn. Containers location is defined in hadoop conf, you can refer conf if it is difficult to find logs.Each container have 3 files:

- stderr
- stdout
- syslogs
  So you may find your output in stdout. 
  You may also use web ui at port 8088 to see output on browser.

Comment: I did a more detailed answer in that post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344114/oozie-launch-map-reduce-from-oozie-java-action/34359732#34359732 based on command-line tools.