# Apache oozie Launcher ERROR

Tags: apache, hadoop, oozie

I am want to run sqoop action using apache oozie but it always giving me error:

```
Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], main() threw exception, null
```

my workflow.xml is:

```
<workflow-app name="Datashop-Core-Sqoop" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1">
<!--    <start to="inputAvailableCheckDecision"/>
         <decision name="inputAvailableCheckDecision">
                <switch>
                        <case to="sqoopAction">
                                ${sqoopInputRecordCount gt minRequiredRecordCount}
                        </case>
                        <default to="end"/>
                </switch>
        </decision> -->
    <start to="sqoopAction"/>
            <action name="sqoopAction">
                <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
                        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
                        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
                        <configuration>
                                <property>
                                        <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                                        <value>${queueName}</value>
                                </property>
                                <property>
                                        <name>oozie.libpath</name>
                                        <value>${oozieLibPath}</value>
                                </property>
                        </configuration>
                        <command>import --connect jdbc:mysql://${mysqlServer}/${mysqlServerDB} --username ${mysqlServerDBUID} --password ${mysqlServerDBPwd} --tabltable ${mysqlTable} -m 1 --target-dir ${targetDir}</command>
                </sqoop>
                <ok to="end"/>
                <error to="killJob"/>
        </action>
        <kill name="killJob">
                <message>"Killed job due to error: ${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}"</message>
        </kill>
        <end name="end" />
</workflow-app>
```

this always throwing sqoopmain class exception which is finally  treating as Error:

```
@sqoopAction] ERROR is considered as FAILED for SLA
```

In some stack question i found that external library is need to be included with `<file>`

so i changed my workflow.xml and add a line below `<command>` tag:

```
<file>${oozieLibPath}/sqoop/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar#mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar</file>
```

But still same error is producing what may be the reason for this error. is there any thing else i need to configure?

Comment: My 2 cents: start with **browsing the logs** carefully to zoom on the actual issue, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344114/oozie-launch-map-reduce-from-oozie-java-action/34359732#34359732 >> then update your post accordingly

Comment: BTW: what kind of Oozie install -- packaged with a distro or custom-built? are the default ShareLibs installed, and if yes, with which version of Sqoop? Did you try the "use system libpath" property instead of setting a custom path?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter i hahve distro package of oozie and yes i have installed sharelibs and i can verify it by "oozie admin -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -shareliblist" . except this sqoop version is 1.4.6. and in my job.properties file i have used "oozie.use.system.libpath=true"

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter i followd your link for debugging and in "yarn logs" i found following error. i searched for it but nothing worked. logs of yarn is:       log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1450691245638_0001/container_1450691245638_0001_01_000001 (Is a directory)

Comment: Not a YARN problem but a Log4J config issue. Question is, what component lacks a log4j.properties file *(your MR job? the Oozie launcher? sthg else??)*, and which logger lacks a specific entry in that file (...)

Comment: I'm not 100% convinced that the Log4J issue is critical enough to fail your job, though. Usually the damn thing just complains and falls back to StdErr as default.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter yes even i thought the same but whenever i tried to run oozie workflow it always coming up with same error `main() threw exception, null` . may be inside command sqoopMain class is not getting its required args.