# Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain], exit code [12]

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I am getting below error while running a hive action in oozie:

```
015-12-20 19:48:40,368  WARN HiveActionExecutor:523 - 
    SERVER[sandbox.hortonworks.com] USER[root] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[oozie_hive_root] 
    JOB[0000013-151220142557945-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000013-151220142557945-oozie-oozi-W@oozie_hive_root] 
    Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain], 
    exit code [12]
```

Few Details about my config:

1. I have renamed the hive-site XML to hive-config xml as suggested in some posts.
2. I have also placed my hive script file(hive.hql) ,hive-config.xml and hive shared lib JAR's  in workflow directory.
3. Have also set the value of - oozie.use.system.libpath=true.
4. selected the hive-config.xml in File as well as JOB XML in oozie workflow.
5. I am using OOZIE 4.2.0 in Hue 2.6.1 browser.

Tried all possible helps from different posts but couldn't got rid of this error.Kindly provide help on this.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: This is just a high-level Oozie error that means that your Hive job has failed. Look at the application logs for the Hive job and you'll find the actual error.

Comment: where will i get the application logs?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344114/oozie-launch-map-reduce-from-oozie-java-action/34359732#34359732

Comment: Hi pradeep, 
Could you pls post the logs which present in STDOUT and STDERR in YARN ?
so that you can able to find the exact error details.

Comment: Hi karthik, I get beloe error while trying to view he STDOUT and STDERR Or, Syslog:User [dr.who] is not authorized to view the logs for attempt_1451244772359_0001_m_000000_0 in log file [sandbox.hortonworks.com_45454]


Unable to locate 'stdout' log for container container_e05_1451244772359_0001_01_000002

Comment: Hi Karthik, here the job is failing:  WARN HiveActionExecutor:523 - SERVER[sandbox.hortonworks.com] USER[root] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[hiveoozie] JOB[0000000-151227193155218-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-151227193155218-o@hiveoozie] Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain], exit code [12]
2015-12-27 20:20:52,036  INFO ActionEndXCommand:520 - SERVER[sandbox.hortonworks.com] USER[root] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[hiveoozie] JOB[0000000-151227193155218-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-151227193155218-oozie-oozi-W@hiveoozie] ERROR is considered as FAILED for SLA

Comment: Any one kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

I solve the same problem. My problem was missing atlas jar files.I was using Hortonworks. If you are using HoetonWorks try to copy all the jar file in /usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/atlas/hook/hive/* directory into lib folder at job.properties level.

Comment: can you explain, if we are not using atlas