# Oozie spark action error: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain], exit code [1]

Tags: apache-spark, oozie

I am currently setting up an Oozie workflow that uses a Spark action. The Spark code that I use works correctly, tested on both local and YARN. However, when running it as an Oozie workflow I am getting the following error:

`Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain], exit code [1]`

Having read up on this error, I saw that the most common cause was a problem with Oozie sharelibs. I have added all Spark jar files to the Oozie /user/oozie/share/lib/spark on hdfs, restarted Oozie and run `sudo -u oozie oozie admin -oozie http://192.168.26.130:11000/oozie -sharelibupdate`
 to ensure the sharelibs are properly updated. Unforunately none of this has stopped the error occurring.

My workflow is as follows:

```
<workflow-app xmlns='uri:oozie:workflow:0.4' name='SparkBulkLoad'>
    <start to = 'bulk-load-node'/>
    <action name = 'bulk-load-node'>
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <master>yarn</master>
            <mode>client</mode>
            <name>BulkLoader</name>
            <jar>${nameNode}/user/spark-test/BulkLoader.py</jar>
            <spark-opts>
                --num-executors 3 --executor-cores 1 --executor-memory 512m --driver-memory 512m\
            </spark-opts>
        </spark>
        <ok to = 'end'/>
        <error to = 'fail'/>
    </action>
    <kill name = 'fail'>
        <message>
            Error occurred while bulk loading files
        </message>
    </kill>
    <end name = 'end'/>
</workflow-app>
```

and job.properties is as follows:

```
nameNode=hdfs://192.168.26.130:8020
jobTracker=http://192.168.26.130:8050
queueName=spark
oozie.use.system.libpath=true

oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/spark-test/workflow.xml
workflowAppUri=${nameNode}/user/spark-test/BulkLoader.py
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest that you look at the *actual* stack trace instead of just guessing. Search the oozie log for labels like `job_00000000_0000` then search the YARN logs for that job, cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344114/oozie-launch-map-reduce-from-oozie-java-action/34359732#34359732

Comment: By the way, there is a big difference between a Spark job that you run from an edge node (using a local Spark install, local conf files, local environment variables, local default CLASSPATH, etc.) and a Spark job started by Oozie on a random Hadoop node. Do you have the Spark runtime installed on each node? With exactly the same version, config, Python version? Do you depend on specific env. variables? Do you depend on some Hadoop JARs in the CLASSPATH *(check YARN StdOut for container 00002 to see what the Oozie Launcher did dump for debugging purposes)*?

Comment: PS: if Spark is downloaded on-the-fly thanks to the Oozie ShareLib, bar the comment about *"Do you have the Spark runtime installed on each node"*, but check what kind of config is attached. Maybe the ShareLib ships only the JARs and you must attach your own config files. And by the way I hope for you that the cluster does not use Kerberos.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Thanks for the comments. I will update my question with some more details. I should have mentioned this is the HDP 2.3 VM which runs a single node 'cluster' so it isn't an issue of differing Spark versions. And it doesn't run Kerberos. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Thanks for your advice. I found my problem; Oozie didn't like that the Python script was on HDFS. Using a local Python script solves this problem (but of course, leads to others)

Comment: *"the Python script was on HDFS"* - then just tell Oozie to download it at run time, into the container's CWD, with `<file>some/hdfs/path/myscript.py</file>`

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter How does kerberos impact things?

Comment: @swinefish Did you finally manage to get it working?

Comment: @anmolkoul > https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/DG_ActionAuthentication.html does NOT mention any "credentials" for a Spark action.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter.. You have a valid point. I am not able to pinpoint any other cause. All i see are  Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain], exit code [1] errors

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter i am just trying to run a word count using spark

Comment: @anmolkoul > use `--principal` and `--keytab` arguments for Spark, and ship the keytab with an Oozie `<file>`. Spark will handle the gory authentication steps by itself.

Answer (score 1):

I have also specified the libpath

```
oozie.libpath=<path>/oozie/share/lib/lib_<timestamp>
```

It is the value you see after the command you wrote

```
sudo -u oozie oozie admin -oozie http://192.168.26.130:11000/oozie -sharelibupdate
```

Example:

```
[ShareLib update status]
    sharelibDirOld = hdfs://nameservice1/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20190328034943
    host = http://vghd08hr.dc-ratingen.de:11000/oozie
    sharelibDirNew = hdfs://nameservice1/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20190328034943
    status = Successful
```

Optional:
You can also specify the yarn configuration within Cloudera folder:

```
oozie.launcher.yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env=/opt/SP/apps/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera4-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.603055/lib/spark2
```

**BUT**
This might not solve the issue. The other hint I have is if you are using Spark 1.x this folder is necessary in your oozie sharelib folder

```
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20190328034943/spark2/oozie-sharelib-spark.jar
```

If you copy it in your spark2 folder, it solves the issue of the "missing SparkMain" but ask for other dependencies (it might be a problem in my environment). I think it worth a try, so copy and paste the lib, run your job, and see the logs.