# Oozie Error Code: E1100 & ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], exit code [1]

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-falcon

Hello I am trying to do this example [Hadoop Data Pipeline](https://github.com/sainib/hadoop-data-pipeline) ...here I am running a Flume agent where Flume copies files from local to HDFS & Falcon does the job of processing data files & after data is processed,Hive processing lineage will be available in Apache Atlas...but the Oozie job is failing as I see on Oozie Web UI...I went through the logs of Oozie & Falcon & in the logs of Oozie,I don`t see the main reason for the Error but I am seeing this 2 errors : **Oozie Error Code: E1100** & **ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], exit code [1](https://github.com/sainib/hadoop-data-pipeline)** ..I can't get any solution to solve this problem....what can be the root cause of this error ?? Thank You

Comment: I suggest that you look at the actual stack trace instead of just guessing. Search the oozie log for labels like `job_00000000_0000` then search the YARN logs for that job, cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344114/oozie-launch-map-reduce-from-oozie-java-action/34359732#34359732

Comment: Get complete ooize job logs and check for the exception. `oozie job -log <job_id>`

Comment: @YoungHobbit: the question *already* displays the Oozie logs. Alas, the useful stuff is in the YARN logs (probably in the AppMaster container i.e. _00001 because it's an init issue, by the look of it)