# Where does hue log its std output and str error.?

Tags: logging, workflow, oozie, hue

I am running a workflow in hue oozie. This workflow has a shell script which runs. I need to know what is the location of logs are present. I'm able to see the logs from hue browser but i don't know the location where it is stored. I need to access this std err from unix for some other process.

Please help

Comment: Hue does not store any Job logs, it pulls them from the YARN consoles

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344114/oozie-launch-map-reduce-from-oozie-java-action/34359732#34359732