# Oozie error - Failing Oozie Launcher With Pig Script

Tags: apache-pig, cloudera, oozie, cloudera-manager

I am trying to run a simple Pig script and have scheduled it via Oozie , however , I get the following Oozie error after the script is run.

I am using Cloudera Enterprise Data Hub Edition Trial 5.6.0 (#54 built by jenkins on 20160211-1910 git: 1c2be84380aa23bd5d6993ec300e144c78b37bf2) .

```
>     2016-04-09 06:37:06,229 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler
> - Using reducer estimator: org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.InputSizeReducerEstimator
>     2016-04-09 06:37:06,237 [uber-SubtaskRunner] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2017: Internal error creating
> job configuration.
>     <<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<
>     Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain], exit code [2]
>     Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully
>     Oozie Launcher, uploading action data to HDFS sequence file: hdfs://node.xxxx.com:8020/user/admin/oozie-oozi/0000000-160409060732867-oozie-oozi-W/pig--pig/action-data.seq
```

**EDIT.**

Additional log info by using the oozie command shell as follows.

```
oozie job -log 0000001-160409063446097-oozie-oozi-W  -oozie http://xxxnode:11000/oozie
```

Gives only the following

```
63446097-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000001-160409063446097-oozie-oozi-W@FirstJob] Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain], exit code [2]
```

Comment: Welcome to the fun world of distributed systems... The full Java stack trace is in the log of the **YARN container**, Oozie just polls the status periodically. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344114/oozie-launch-map-reduce-from-oozie-java-action/34359732#34359732

Comment: Thank you , please see the edit .

Comment: Search StackOverflow for `ERROR 2017` and you will find a lot of similar posts. Seems to result from a number of possible bugs in the way Pig generates its execution plan. Hopefully the other posts have suggestions of workarounds.